# The constructor Skin(TextureAtlas) is undefined libgdx

Tags: android, textures, libgdx, skin

I'm coding for android using libgdx but when I try to create a skin using a TextureAtlas, eclipse throws me an error saying to remove argument or change type to FileHandle

```
atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/packs/button.pack"));
skin = new Skin(atlas);
```

Comment: seems like the constructor Skin(TextureAtlas) is undefined

Comment: yea but documentation says there is a constructor defined for that    http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Skin.html#Skin(com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas)

Comment: yeah, i saw that .... maybe you are using version without this constructor(i mean older)

Comment: Try to download the latest build (0.9.9) or the nightlies. Tell us the result then

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Skin.java
I took a look at the source code. The constructor with TextureAtlas should exist. try to write `new Skin` in Eclipse and then press `ctrl + space`. It should show all possible constructors. If  the constructor with `TextureAtlas` does not work try to download a new version.

Comment: yep, I used 0.9.5 version. Proved on 0.9.9 and works fine. Thanks!